# Attach Click event to div to get inner div value

Tags: jquery

I want to attach onclick event to "month_head" class and get value of inner div. Anyone please

```
<td>
    <div class="month_head">
        <div >13</div>
    </div>
    <div class="month_body" ></div>
</td>
<td>
    <div class="month_head">
        <div >14</div>
    </div>
    <div class="month_body" ></div>
</td>
<td>
    <div class="month_head">
        <div >15</div>
    </div>
    <div class="month_body" ></div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind onclick with`.click()`, then find the child div passing `this` as the context, and get `.text()`.

```
$(".month_head").click(function () {
    var val = $("> div", this).text();
    // do something with val
});
```

If the only content in your `month_head` div is the child div, you can skip finding the child div and just call `.text()`.

```
var val = $(this).text();
```

Comment: Your solution was not working but using  $(".month_head").live("click", function () {}); worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.month_head').click(function() {
   alert( $(this).children('div').html() );
});
```

Use `.children('div')` or `.find('div')` to get the nested `div`.

- `.children()` only looks at direct descendant elements
- `.find()` looks at all descendant elements

In the handler, `this` represents the element that was clicked, and `$(this)` places that element in a jQuery object, which gives you access to the methods.

---

In jQuery 1.7 or later, you could do this instead:

```
$('.month_head').on('click',function() {
   alert( $(this).children('div').html() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.month_head').click(function() {
    var your_divs_html = $('div', this).html();
    alert(your_divs_html); // will alert 13/14/15
});
```